# Getting lost in an existing JS project

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, node.js, cordova

I got into an existing JS project, a sole programmer has been working on it for 6 months and left without much explaining.
Anyway it is written in Ionic, and from what I have read and tested, just a tool for building cordova + angular applications.
Anyway I got the app deployed on my phone fine, cordova command line and even can get a server with Ionic serve, which is very familiar to other node servers.
My problem is developing. I'm used to get the app running on my pc, checking stuff with dev tools, see when and where is a resource being accessed to and more. The app working perfectly normal on my mobile but when getting to the pc I can't get past the login screen with the error "cordova is not defined". Checking the code more it is heavily depended on cordova. What can I do to solve this?
Here is a sample code from the project which I run into error on login:

```
var dir = window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(dir) {
dir.getDirectory("build/", {create:true}, function(aDir) {
    FS.builds = aDir;
}, FS.fsError);
dir.getDirectory("assets/", {create:true}, function(aDir) {
    FS.assets = aDir;
    App.assetURL = FS.assets.toURL();
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("FS-ready", {}));
}, FS.fsError);
}, FS.fsError);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: cordova added the browser platform long time ago, try to add the browser platform to your project, and then it might work (to add browser platform use "cordova platform add browser")

Answer (score 1):

The mobile application as MVC *(Model-View-Controller)* contains two parts:

- Native code (Android - Java/ Obj-C/Swift - iOS) - *Model*
- Ionic(GUI) + Angular + Cordova - *View + Controller*

By Cordova interfaces GUI can talk with native part.

When you try to run `www` as root in browser (apache or similar), it tells you that cordova is not defined since  Browser hasn't cordova sources (it stored in mobile assets).

Your application starts on mobile when Cordova is ready that doesn't happen in Browser.

Anyways to run your project in Browser(Chrome ...) since you use Angular, Controllers talk 1st with Services. Create some folder `data` with `json` files that simulate responses from mobile native to Angular and instead to call cordova API, call by `$http.get` your json file.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid() ) {
     $rootScope.imAndroid = true;
   }
   else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() ) {
     $rootScope.imiOS = true;
   }
    else{
       $rootScope.imBrowser = true;
    }
}
```

in some service:

```
// load JSON data by async way with promise 
app.factory('Items', ['$http',
    function($http) {

        return {
            getJson: function(url) {
                var ItemsJson = $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
                return ItemsJson;
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

So Example looks like:

```
self.login = function(){

       if ($rootScope.imBrowser === true) {
             // in Browser we call JSON file
             return Items.getJson('data/loginResponse.json');
        }

       if ( (ionic.Platform.isAndroid() || ionic.Platform.isIOS() )) {  
              // on mobile we call Cordova
              return CordovaService.login();              
         }
   };
```

Comment: That's a lot of code I'll be needing to write to make my browser compatible too.. as I said, the code is heavily depended on cordova

Comment: well, there is no other alternative way (or I don't know one) and you need write only `if` case for every cordova case, most work is to generate JSON files with fictive data

Comment: Hey guys.

I actually found an answer on cordova's forums and wanted to get back here and share.
For android development (Also available for ios with safari), you can use chrome dev tool to inspect a webpage on the mobile, even if it is in a webview like cordova.

Read more about Chrome's remote dubugging (chrome://inspect/#devices)

Comment: @YuvalSaraf, hmm, this is not what you asked for. Sure you can debug with Chrome and Safari but real mobile device. The way I showed up is to develop GUI without mobile because it takes time to copy web code to mobile and run from Xcode or Eclipse.